# How to check if a NSTimer is running or not in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to check if NSTimer is running or not in Swift. In obj-c the code should be like this as I guess:

```
if (!myTimer) {
  //DO
}
```

I'm trying to set it in Swift like this and it's showing errors.

```
if !myTimer {
 // DO
}
```

Comment: Provide all the pertinent  information, that would include the actual full error message.

Comment: @amro shahbari swift 3.1 not working

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What I do (in both languages) is to make my timer weak. In swift it would be a weak optional.

```
weak var myTimer: NSTimer?
```

Then I create a timer with

```
myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,
          target: self,
          selector: "timerFired:",
          userInfo: nil,
          repeats: false)
```

And then you can use

```
if timer == nil
```

to tell if it's running.

To stop the timer you just call

```
myTimer?.invalidate()
```

In Objective-C it would be

```
[myTimer invalidate];
```

That works in Objective-C because sending messages to nil pointers is valid, and just does nothing.

If you don't want to use a weak optional, you can query a timer to see if it's running by looking at it's `valid` property.

Comment: Just because `timer` is not nil does not tell if it is running.

Comment: It does if you make it weak. Then the only owning reference is the run loop, and after it fires/when it's invalidated, it gets released and nil'ed out. It's handy.

Comment: No, with a weak pointer,   
timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: creates a timer which is immediately deallocated because it has zero strong references.. That is a degenerate case. Try what I describe. It works. I promise.

Comment: For this to work `myTimer` must be declared as a `weak` property as you show, which is a key point.

Comment: As an aside I was testing in `main` with this runloop: `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];` and that is  insufficient to demonstrate the `weak` nilling.

Comment: `isValid` can't be used to check if the timer is running or not. It tells if the timer is still capable of firing or not. If the timer is created with one of the init methods, meaning it's not added to any run loop and therefore it's not running, `isValid` returns true.

Answer (score 22):

How about the below option? Can you see if this works for you

```
if myTimer.valid {
}
```

Comment: For this to work `myTimer` must be declared as a `weak` property.

Comment: @zaph, no. My approach of making it weak and checking for nil works, OR you can make it strong and then check to see if timer.valid == true. Using `myTimer.valid` does **NOT** require that `myTimer` be weak.

Answer (score 6):

```
if !myTimer.valid {
    //DO
}
```

Comment: For this to work `myTimer` must be declared as a `weak` property.

Comment: @zaph, that is wrong. For this approach the timer **can't** be declared weak.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 answer:

```
if timer.isValid{

            }
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer